# Prevent Windows from Freezing and becoming unresponsive to any attempts to wake when sleeping automatically

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I bought a PC from someone to learn with and it keeps freezing. It works normally, but when it falls asleep, it won't wake up and I have to force it off by holding the power button. If it just goes to display sleep, mouse or keyboard will wake it normally, but it will freeze and become completely unresponsive to input. I want it to sleep, I just want it to wake up when I use the keyboard or mouse.

It came with a clean install of Windows 7. I wiped and did a clean install of Windows 10, and the issue persists.

This computer's job is a media server. I can't remote into it or wake the display once it goes to sleep. It's still present on the network but I can't "get in" to it or pull files via SMB. I have no clue what the problem could be. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Open  the start menu, type Choose a power plan, hit enter. Then expand the "Hide additional plans" then select High performance, Then click "Change Plan Settings", Then click "Change advanced power settings", Then expand PCI Express, Then Link State Power Management, set that to off. Then click apply, then Save Changes.

Comment: Hey I stopped using this PC bc of this but thanks for answering.

Comment: I don't know why this was edited to say "Going to sleep." It's not going to sleep, it's FREEZING.

Answer (score 0):

So, have you try in cmd with admin credentials:

this: `powercfg /setactive 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c`

set power scheme to high performance, not save energi, so not sleep!

this: `powercfg /hibernate off`

set hibernate to off, prevent sleep (a paranoid resource in my case!)

```
 powercfg /setactive 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
 powercfg.exe /hibernate off
```

See line above, more details in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723339/changing-power-scheme-settings-through-registry-instead-of-control-panel-in-wind):

```
powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -change -standby-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -change -hibernate-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -change -standby-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -change -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -change -standby-timeout-dc 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Can you please [edit] your answer, and explain *why* that works, and what those commands do? Otherwise, this will likely get flagged as low quality and deleted